# How to add a close button or clear code in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I have a gallery of pictures (dynamically fetched from a json).
When I open the link, picture pops up, but I am not able to close it.

I would need either to add some kind of "Close button" or just to clear the code (onclick event?).

```
createImg.setAttribute("src", books[i].cover)
createImg.setAttribute("alt", "Avatar")
createImg.setAttribute("style", "width:290px;height:380px;")

 var createButton = document.createElement("button");
createButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
createButton.setAttribute("id", books[i].detail);
createButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var showPicture = document.getElementById("showPictureID")

// - clean code or close button (on click ??)

  var createDet = document.createElement('img');
     createDet.setAttribute("src", event.target.id)
  createDet.setAttribute("alt", "image")
  createDet.setAttribute("style", "position:fixed;top:20%;left:20%;")

  var showPicture = document.getElementById("showPictureID")
  showPicture.appendChild(createDet);
```

Not sure how to approach this. Its a long code, thus I'm pasting just a part of it... Up we have fetching

Any ideas are very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before creating img element "createDet" you can create button element for deleting

```
var closeBtn = document.createElement('button');
closeBtn.innerHTML = "Close image";
showPicture.appendChild(closeBtn);

closeBtn.addEventListener ("click", function() {
    var showPicture = document.getElementById("showPictureID");
    var imgTag = showPicture.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]; //or use more precise selection for image that must be closed
    showPicture.removeChild(imgTag);

    var btnTag = showPicture.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]; //remove the close button too
    showPicture.removeChild(btnTag);
});
```

Style the button with css as you wish.

If showPicture contains only the picture, you can just empty it, but
you should use only one of event listeners not both.

```
closeBtn.addEventListener ("click", function() {
    var showPicture = document.getElementById("showPictureID");
    showPicture.innerHTML = '';
});
```

Comment: amazing understanding of the issue Artus! Thanks! 
I am very new with JS and struggling with a lot of things... 

Can you just clarify the "var imgTag"
not sure where I use imgTag. If you ment the image tag, this is how my HTML looks:

  <div id="cardPlace" class="card-container"></div>
  <div id="showPictureID"></div>

Thats basically it, all is done via JS....

Comment: the second part doesnt work... not sure if I copied it to the right spot in the code. 

not sure if you can see the screenshot...
https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AACpGC6jqk0RJJ2trozx73QAjLPCBBqydGs

Comment: took me a bit to figure it out, but it does work. Thanks! 
Now I just need to hide the button ;)

Comment: I created imgTag so I can select the image tag from your showPicture element and then remove it.

Comment: Ahh, btnTag was suposed for remowing the button. My mistake. I corrected it. Now it should work. ;)

Comment: FilipZafran, I wish you success with learning JS. Learning by real world struggles is very good approach in my opinion.